# NotImplementedError: bounds checking is not supported for CUDA

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to run code on my GPU, and firstly I clashed with the problem of having a working CUDA on ubuntu 18.04. After some pain I was suggested to work in a Docker Image, where I have (I presume) a well working CUDA version (I'm starting learning pytorch, and I was able to obtain a `torch.cuda.is_available() = True`).

After that I tried to run a simple code copied [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-script-on-gpu/), in order to see if effectively my GPU was able to do its job.

Unfortunately not... I receive the message:

```
NotImplementedError: bounds checking is not supported for CUDA
```

and I really wasn't able to understand a proper way to fix it.

This is what I obtain if I run `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940M        On   | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    242MiB /  2004MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this is what I obtain if I run `nvcc --version`

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Comment: https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/4432/files

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html

Comment: https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/4432

Comment: The error is raised at https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/d7953a18dbf5ea231dc16e967ce8e9b754578ea6/numba/cuda/simulator/api.py#L79

Comment: or at https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/d7953a18dbf5ea231dc16e967ce8e9b754578ea6/numba/cuda/decorators.py#L55

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1069404/jetson-tx2/testing-the-excecution-with-and-with-out-gpu-and-cuda-in-jetson-tx2/post/5420342/#5420342

Comment: Could you please post the full error message so we can see in which file it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the community is dealing with some [bugs](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/4432)

So I tried some hacks and it actually worked!!!

Just changed the line

@jit(target ="cuda")

to

@jit

[image: Just for]